# Custom Overflow Menu Outside of ActionBar

Tags: android

I need to implement a custom overflow menu with menu items and the overflow icon if the screen size cannot show all the icons.  I cannot use a side scroll since I am already inside an expanded list view.  I cannot use the Top or bottom action bar menu because the action will change based on what list item has been expanded.

So I would like to create my own overflow menu - similar to the gmail screenshots attached

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

Any ideas?  Apparently ABS can be used for this but I can't figure it out, please help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ListPopupWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) is what you're looking for. It's an API 11+ class, however. ABS includes a backported version which is basically just a `ListView` inside a `PopupWindow` (both API 1 classes).

Comment: I can create the drop down list, but how do you make it "showIfRoom"? and attach that to the other items in the layout?

Comment: This was only half of the solution.  I went and created my own overflow layout and measured the drawables that were getting put into it until it was full then placed a IcsListPopupWindow at the end.... If anyone has a better solution let me know

Comment: That's exactly what the action bar does. There is no re-usable component for this behavior because it is highly specific to whatever you're implementing.